# set selected value in Select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to set the selected value of Select2 dropdown. I am displaying two types of address which contains Address and invoice address. Each will have the following fields:

1. Address 1 - textbox
2. Address 2 - textbox
3. Town - textbox
4. country - dropdown

Invoice address also has these same fields. Also, I am displaying one checkbox, if it is clicked, we should copy the address fields values to invoice address fields.
I can able to copy the textbox values and set to another textboxes. But I'm unable to copy the dropdown values and set to another dropdown. I used the following code:

```
$('#invoiceAddress').on('ifChecked', function (event) {
    $('input[data-cg-address]').each(function (index, element) {
        var fieldname = $(this).data('cg-address');
        var fieldvalue = $(this).val();
        $('#invoice-address').find('input[data-invoice-address="' + fieldname +   '"]').val(fieldvalue);
    });

    $('select[data-cg-address]').each(function (index, element) {
        var fieldname = $(this).data('cg-address');
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        $('#invoice-address').find('select[data-invoice-address="' + fieldname + '"]').val(selectedValue);
    });
});
```

This code was working if it is normal dropdown. It is not working on a Select2 dropdown.

I used this code on few more pages. So I can;t use the id of those dropdowns.
I need to write common code. below are the form fields.

```
 <div class="panel">
                                    <div class="panel-header">
                                        <h3><i class="icon-bulb"></i> Address Details</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="cg-address" class="panel-content">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address1)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address1, new { @class = "form-control", data_cg_address = "address1" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address1)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address2)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address2, new { @class = "form-control", data_cg_address = "address2" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address2)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Town)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Town, new { @class = "form-control", data_cg_address = "town" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Town)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address4)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address4, new { @class = "form-control", data_cg_address = "address4" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Address4)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Postcode)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Postcode, new { @class = "form-control", data_cg_address = "postcode" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.Postcode)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.CountyId)</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.CountyId, new SelectList(Model.Counties, "Key", "Value"), "Select Company County", new { @class = "form-control", data_cg_address = "countyid" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.CountyId)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.CountryId)</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Key", "Value"), "Select Company Country", new { @class = "form-control", data_cg_address = "countryid" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupAddress.CountryId)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="invoice-address" class="panel">
                                    <div class="panel-header">
                                        <h3><i class="icon-bulb"></i>Invoice Address Details</h3>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-content">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">

                                                    <label>
                                                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.InvoiceAddress, new { @id = "invoiceAddress", @for = "invoiceAddress", @class = "m-t-10" })
                                                        Same as Company Address
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address1)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address1, new { @class = "form-control", data_invoice_address = "address1" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address1)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address2)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address2, new { @class = "form-control", data_invoice_address = "address2" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address2)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Town)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Town, new { @class = "form-control", data_invoice_address = "town" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Town)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address4)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address4, new { @class = "form-control", data_invoice_address = "address4" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Address4)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Postcode)</label>
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Postcode, new { @class = "form-control", data_invoice_address = "postcode" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.Postcode)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.CountyId)</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.CountyId, new SelectList(Model.Counties, "Key", "Value"), "Select Company County", new { @class = "form-control", data_invoice_address = "countyid" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.CountyId)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.CountryId)</label>
                                                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.CountryId, new SelectList(Model.Countries, "Key", "Value"), "Select Company Country", new { @class = "form-control", data_invoice_address = "countryid" })
                                                    <div class="form-error">
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CompanyGroupInvoiceAddress.CountryId)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('#checkbox').click(function(){
    var dropdown1 = $('#dropdown1').val();

    $('#dropdown2').val(dropdown1);
});
```

Comment: I used this code on few more pages. So I can;t use the id of those dropdowns. I need to write common code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $("#chkbox").click(function () {
         var options = $('#ddl1 option').clone();
        $('#ddl2').append(options);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" />
<select id="ddl1">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>            
</select>

<select id="ddl2">
```

Comment: I used this code on few more pages. So I can;t use the id of those dropdowns. I need to write common code.

Comment: Given code is not working. could you please check it?

Comment: you can write input[type='checkbox']

Comment: No, its not correct way. it is just append values from one dropdown to another dropdown each time click the checkbox. i want to copy the selected value of first dropdown and set that to another dropdown.

Comment: it is standard code to copy data from one dropdown to another.

Comment: I want jquery code to set the value of select2 dropdown when click the check box. you can refer my jquery code in my question. that code was working fine on normal dropdowns. Now we changed all dropdowns to "Select2" dropdown style. so this code is not working.

Comment: If you want to set value to select2 you can use something like that: 
Set your select2 element first : $("your_select2_element").select2(); and after that :
$("your_select2_element").val("value_to_set").trigger("change");

Answer (score 0):

I just added the code in trigger('change') in dropdownlist set value as below.

```
 $('#invoice-address').find('select[data-invoice-address="' + fieldname + '"]').val(selectedValue).trigger("change");
```

Now it is working fine.